# How to split camera preview in android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I want to achieve this kind of feature.

My initial camera preview:

> [image]

Now I want to break this camera preview in two parts:

> [image]

What I have tried:

1. Create a surface view to hold preview of camera.[Done]
2. Shift  half of the surface view out off the screen[Done] now half of the surface view shift from out off the screen and only half is visible.

The problem is camera writes it's complete preview only on visible portion of surface view so the preview gets shrink in half of the screen.

Can anybody help me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Send the camera preview to a SurfaceTexture, then draw two rects with GLES, one with the left part of the preview, one with the right. Use a single SurfaceView for display.

You can find sample code in [Grafika's](https://github.com/google/grafika) "texture from Camera" Activity, which manipulates the camera output in various ways.  Note in particular the "zoom" feature works by displaying a progressively smaller area of the preview while keeping the output rect the same size.

Comment: Thanks for help.Can you please tell me how can I get the right and left part of preview ?

Comment: You select it by modifying the texture coordinates, which specify the source region using the range [0.0,1.0]. The [ScaledDrawable2d](https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/ScaledDrawable2d.java) class does this to select the inner portion of the preview area to create the zoom effect. You'd do something similar, but with U from 0 to 1, and V from 0 to 0.5 or 0.5 to 1.